# Combining two fields in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table I have a field "firstname" and a field "lastname". I would like to select all records where firstname + space + lastname is a certain value.

I've tried this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sam_users WHERE (user_firstname + ' ' + user_lastname LIKE ?)";
```

But this isn't working. With Google I've found something about using ||, but I don't really understand how I should use that operator. Note that I don't want to use an or-operator (what || is in many languages), but something to concatenate 2 fields (with a space between them) and using a LIKE on that.

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? And why are you using `LIKE` rather than `=`?

Comment: MySQL, but I'm using the PDO library (PHP) so it should be portable. I'm using LIKE because I'm making a "search" field, so the result should be a list of all users who's name is like the entered string.

Comment: @Bv202 - Not sure if there is a "most portable" string concatenation method. Will be interested myself if any of the answers cover that.

Comment: Do you want WHERE user_firstname LIKE(?) AND user_lastname LIKE(?)?

Comment: No, I really need something like the CONCAT keyword

Comment: Please be aware that not everyone uses their first name and last name, and some people don't even have them. Some people just have a single name. Some have names where the first name is the family name, not the last name. Some people have three names and their last one is not normally used.

Comment: For reference on naming conventions: [personal names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name). Since 'first_name last_name' describes the order but not function of names, it's not as bad as a 'given_name surname' scheme. Having "fullname" and "shortname" (there must be a better term for a name someone is addressed by) columns is better, as it is more easily encompasses different naming conventions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With MySQL, you can use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT * FROM sam_users 
  WHERE CONCAT(user_firstname, ' ', user_lastname) LIKE ?
```

or [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) (which ignores NULL values):

```
SELECT * FROM sam_users 
  WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', user_firstname, user_lastname) LIKE ?
```

However, MySQL won't be able to use any [indices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html) when performing this query. If the value of the pattern argument to `LIKE` begins with a wildcard, MySQL won't be able to use indices, so comparing to a generated value (instead of a column) won't make a difference.

You can also set the [MySQL server SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html) to ["ANSI"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) or ["PIPES_AS_CONCAT"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) to use the `||` operator for string concatenation.

```
SET @@sql_mode=CONCAT_WS(',', @@sql_mode, 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT');
SELECT * FROM sam_users 
  WHERE (user_firstname || ' ' || user_lastname) LIKE ?
```

This sets the SQL mode for the current [session](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-option.html) only. You'll need to set `@@sql_mode` each time you connect. If you wish to unset 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT' mode in a session:

```
SET @@sql_mode=REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT', '');
```

MySQL appears to remove any extra commas in `@@sql_mode`, so you don't need to worry about them.

Don't use [`SELECT *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select); select only the columns you need.

Comment: Oh well, way too easy... somehow I must have missed the CONCAT keyword... Thanks for the link regarding SELECT *; that's interesting :)

Comment: What about using count(*)? Is that also a bad thing?

Comment: @Bv202: Not at all. `COUNT(*)` is a special case. The columns themselves aren't examined for the tally (though they will be for any other clauses), just the matching rows. Even without this optimization, changing a table definition won't affect `COUNT(*)` in ways that would cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL the `||` operator *does* mean string concatenation according to the standard (see SQL 2008: 5.2). The boolean or operator is written `OR` in SQL.

However not all databases implement it this way and so the exact syntax depends on the specific database.

- MySQL Server uses the [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.
- MSSQL Server uses the [`+`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx) operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sam_users 
WHERE  TRIM(Concat(user_firstname, ' ', user_lastname)) LIKE ?;
```